# Save spark dataframe schema to hdfs

Tags: hdfs, apache-spark-sql

For a given data frame (df) we get the schema by df.schema, which is a StructType array. Can I save just this schema onto hdfs, while running from spark-shell? Also, what would be the best format in which the schema should be saved?

Comment: [Please Refer this: I think You will find the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816767/how-to-save-result-of-printschema-to-a-file-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `treeString`

```
schema = df._jdf.schema().treeString()
```

and convert it to an RDD and use **saveAsTextFile**:

```
sc.parallelize([schema ]).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

Or to use **saveAsPickleFile**:

```
temp_rdd = sc.parallelize(schema)
temp_rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsPickleFile("s3a://path/to/destination_schema.pickle")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Yes, you can save the schema as df.write.format("parquet").save("path") 
#Give path as a HDFS path

You can read also hdfs sqlContext.read.parquet("Path") #Give HDFS Path

Parquet + compression is the best storage strategy whether it resides on S3 
or not.

Parquet is a columnar format, so it performs well without iterating over all 
columns.
Please refer this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361222/dataframe-to-hdfs-in-spark-
scala
```

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with that approach, it saves the complete data frame, I am interested in just saving the schema `df.schema` onto hdfs.

Comment: I am not sure about that.I didn't get any article about this also. So if you will get to know please tell me also.

Comment: I figured a way to make it work - `val rdd = sc.parallelize(df.schema)` `rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsObjectFile("<hdfs_path>")`  `val rdd2: RDD[StructField] = sc.objectFile("<hdfs_path>")` `StructType(rdd2.collect())`

Comment: If using Python, `saveAsPickleFile` and `pickleFile` should be used as `saveAsObjectFile` and `objectFile` aren't available.