# How to save result of printSchema to a file in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have used `df.printSchema()` in pyspark and it gives me the schema with tree structure. Now i need to save it in a variable or a text file.

I have tried below methods of saving but they didn't work.

```
v = str(df.printSchema())  
print(v) 
#and
df.printSchema().saveAsTextFile(<path>)
```

I need the saved schema in below format

```
|-- COVERSHEET: struct (nullable = true)                              
 |    |-- ADDRESSES: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ADDRESS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _primary: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _street: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _zip: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CONTACTS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CONTACT: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `treeString` (which for some reason, I couldn't find in the python API)

```
#v will be a string
v = df._jdf.schema().treeString()
```

You can convert it to a RDD and use `saveAsTextFile`

```
sc.parallelize([v]).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

Or use Python specific API to write a String to a file.

Comment: You've no idea how long I've searched for a solution like this, THANKS BUNCHES

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following:

```
temp_rdd = sc.parallelize(schema)
temp_rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsPickleFile("s3a://path/to/destination_schema.pickle")
```